# Can we use Resource Expressions in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I try to use <%$ Resources:Resource1, Name %> in the view, I am getting an error like

**Literal expressions like '<%$ Resources:Resource1, Name %>' are not allowed. Use <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource1, Name%>" /> instead**

Ta,
Rajeesh

Answer (score 2):

[ASP.NET MVC - Localization Helpers](http://blog.eworldui.net/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC---Localization.aspx)

Comment: This is not I was looking for, I would like to use the resource expression <%$ Resources:Resource1, Name %>

Answer (score 0):

"Plain MVC":

> 